# Who decides if a microbiology lab is BSL-2 compliant in the US?

Tags: united-states, research, enforcement

I am currently searching for a [BSL-2](https://www.cdc.gov/cpr/infographics/biosafety.htm) lab for a microbiology project that I am starting, which lead me to a rather basic question:

I understand that in the US, the CDC defines what each biosafety level entails, but do they also certify/keep track of the labs that are BSL-2? Or is it certified by third parties? Could any company rent a space and make it into a BSL-2 lab given that they outfit it with the required safety equipment etc?

Another way of asking the questions is, how are the CDC's guidelines enforced?

Comment: Similarly, if I want to open a lab and advertise it as BSL-2 compliant, is it sufficient for me to follow all of the BSL-2 precautions or do I also need to get someone to come in and give me a piece of paper that says that I've been inspected and found compliant?

Answer (score 6):

There are no legal requirements for official certification of BSL-1 and BSL-2 laboratories in the US. There are [legal requirements](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-42/chapter-I/subchapter-F/part-73?toc=1) for higher-level labs that deal with Select Agents. The CDC has a [page on certification laws and regulations](https://www.cdc.gov/clia/law-regulations.html), which is "about" samples derived from the human body. Organizations (such as universities) have offices that perform inspections and approve (or not) a particular laboratory, by reference to standard professional guidelines. This is, of course, different from the situation in Europe. There may be state-level legal requirements.

Answer (score 4):

> <sup>[1](https://www.phe.gov/s3/BioriskManagement/biosafety/Pages/Biosafety-FAQ.aspx#over14)</sup>The Federal entities that have primary regulatory oversight responsibility for organizations that possess, use, or transfer infectious agents, toxins, or other biological hazards are:
>
> - Department of Labor (DOL), Occupational Safety and Health Administration (OSHA)
> - Department of Health and Human Services (HHS), the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC) and National Institute for Health (NIH)
> - U.S. Department of Agriculture, Animal and Plant Health Inspection Service (APHIS)
> - U.S. Department of Transportation (DOT)
> - U.S. Department of Commerce (DOC)

Oversight of BSL facilities depends on the types of organisms and activities within the lab. Most research universities have BSL-2 facilities, and those are usually immediately overseen by the university's own environmental health department.

Although mostly involving BSL-3 and BSL-4 facilities, some BSL-2 facilities [are registered](https://www.gao.gov/assets/gao-18-145.pdf) with the US [Select Agent Program](https://www.selectagents.gov/), which oversees possession and use of agents and toxins "which have the potential to pose a severe threat to public, animal or plant health or to animal or plant products."

> The CDC is responsible for the registration and oversight of laboratories that possess, use, or transfer select agents and toxins that could pose a threat to human health. USDA is responsible for the registration and oversight of laboratories that possess, use, or transfer select agents and toxins that could pose a threat to animal or plant health or animal or plant products. Some select agents, such as anthrax, pose a threat to both human and animal health and are regulated by both agencies.<sup>[2](http://www.gao.gov/pdf/product/117997)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

## Certification is required

Incidentally, the BSL levels are not just national, they are almost the same internationally, as they have been developed by international committees for disease control. The only difference between countries is generally the certification process and if you have a private or public certification body, but not what it requires.

BSL laboratories almost always need certification from some institution that checks that they actually follow the regulations before starting work. Pubmed has articles about [common issues and the certification process in **India**](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5819027/). Biomedical Science Letters describes the BSL2 Audit process and requirements [for a **Singaporean** lab.](https://www.bslonline.org/journal/view.html?doi=10.15616/BSL.2016.22.3.65)

Universities typically already have the lab certifications and strict rundowns on how to get into those. A typical rundown of how to access to a BSL-2 lab can be found in the [Rochester University guidelines](https://www.safety.rochester.edu/labbiosafe/bsl2certification.html), which is located in New York. [Carnagie Mellon University](https://www.cmu.edu/ehs/Laboratory-Safety/biological-safety/documents/requirements-for-laboratories-under-biosafety-level-23.pdf) in Pennsylvania has similar rules.  [The university of Wisconsin/Milwaukee](https://uwm.edu/ibc/bsl2_requirements/) offers the guidelines for BSL2 as well.

### Certification is not just for the lab... but for each item in it!

The CDC also has a whole book on the matter. [2009 saw the 5th edition](https://www.cdc.gov/labs/pdf/CDC-BiosafetymicrobiologicalBiomedicalLaboratories-2009-P.pdf), [2020 the 6th](https://www.cdc.gov/labs/pdf/CDC-BiosafetyMicrobiologicalBiomedicalLaboratories-2020-P.pdf). These books also contain specific certification requirements to keep the overall BSL level certification for the lab. For example, a random item I picked is the "Biological Safety Cabinet".

> D. Laboratory Facilities (Secondary Barriers)
>
> 10. BSCs and other primary containment barrier systems are installed and
>     operated in a manner to ensure their effectiveness. See Appendix A.
>
> c. BSCs are certified at least annually to ensure correct performance,
> or as specified in Appendix A, Part 7.

> The evolution of containment equipment for varied research and diagnostic
> applications created the need for consistency in construction and performance.
> Federal Standard 20929 was developed to establish classes of air cleanliness and
> methods for monitoring clean workstations and cleanrooms where HEPA filters
> are used to control airborne particulates. It has since been replaced with **ISO
> 14644-2015**

So the BSC has to comply with [this standard](https://www.iso.org/standard/53394.html) - and as you notice, the standard costs a couple hundred swiss francs and is only to get the *specifications* of the *one* item. Yes, lab certification is *expensive*, as you need to certify a lot of items to get the overall safety certification from the relevant certification agency.

Comment: I agree that labs within an institution typically must follow some institutional guidelines and be certified, but I don't see any legal requirement for this in the US. There are certainly some difficult standards for an individual to comply with without having institutional support, but I don't see anything about, say, UWM, that gives them legal power to certify BSL-2 labs that someone else doesn't have. They've just come up with their own process to make sure they can tell the federal govt "our labs are complying with federal law" which is nice to say when you ask for federal funding.

Comment: It does appear that there are some 3rd-party companies that will audit compliance with BSL-2 regulations, and it seems like it would be wise for an independent lab to consult with someone if nothing else as a shield for liability (and possibly as a condition for having a relevant insurance policy), I just don't see that any of these audits or certifications are mandated.

Comment: @BryanKrause it is indeed generally a 3rd party audit, following the government guidelines from the book pointed out. The problem you get is that without such certification, you can't legally acquire the samples you need for research.

Comment: What is the law or regulation that states you need a certification to legally acquire BSL-2 level samples?

Comment: When you say that "you can't legally acquire the samples" without certification, do you mean that it's *illegal* to acquire them without certiication or that your supplier only supplies to certified labs?

Comment: @RobertColumbia (BMBL 6th Edition. And you can check out for example the https://www.cdc.gov/cpr/ipp/inspection/docs/Import_Permit_Checklist_BSL-2.pdf - import permit, which has lots of pointers.

Comment: @BryanKrause for example https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-42/chapter-I/subchapter-F/part-71/subpart-F/section-71.54 requires a permit for importing them. https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-42/chapter-I/subchapter-B/part-24 specifies who may get a clearance for working with some sample types. https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-42/chapter-I/subchapter-F/part-73/section-73.12 dictates what is to be do with an enumerated list of pathogens. https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-42/chapter-I/subchapter-F/part-75 is the rules how to accredit an educational lab.

Comment: @Trish I don't see what requiring a permit for importing something has to do with operating a BSL-2 lab. The second link doesn't seem to involve what you say it does, and even if it did "clearance for working with some sample types" sounds like possibly it is related to select agents, which has little to nothing to do with BSL-2.